# How to notify a user using email alert on a custom field

Tags: workflow

I have a requirement where I want to notify a user an email alert which is selected on a custom field manually. I have the user's name but do not have the email address on the page layout. This user is different than lead owner or any other system fields.

Please help!!

Comment: If you used a custom lookup field, you'd have an option on the email alert to send to that user's email.

Comment: No we do not have custom lookup we are using picklist

Comment: kunal - see my revised answer

Answer (score 2):

Email alerts are limited in the referenceable entities to those shown in the dialog when you create the Email Alert.

For users (as opposed to Contacts or Leads):

**User**
This would be a hard-coded user who always receives the email alert. Many users can be chosen in the Email Alert dialog

**Related User**
Gives you access to the value of a custom lookup field to User (and hence that user's email). Hence, this is a dynamic value. If you need more than one related user, you need more than one custom User lookup field. A null value in the lookup field will not be a problem as email alerts ignore null recipients.

**Email**
Gives you access to a single email in the custom field of type `Email`. The user creating/updating the record needs to enter a value here (it is not a formula field) or a workflow/process builder flow field update can update, or, a trigger can update. If you need more than one email recipient, use multiple custom fields of type `Email`. You can't send email alerts to comma-separated text field values.

> Update - OP indicates value of user comes from a picklist field

If the record contains a user name in text form (such as from a picklist), you will need to use Process Builder Field Update / Workflow Field Update / or before insert/update Trigger to update a custom lookup User lookup field or custom field of Type Email as noted above